# How can I reset a <select> menu using a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a webpage in which a user will see a  menu with a default text shown (in this case "choose baseline"). After they select one of the options, I need to have a button that can reset the select menu to its 'Choose baseline' default. How can I do this?

```
    <select onchange="saveSelection(value)">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Baseline</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button">Reset menu</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an id on your select. Then add a function `clearSelection` to be triggered on click of the button.

```js
function saveSelection(value) {

}

function clearSelection() {
  //This will select the first option of the select
  document.getElementById('select-baseline').options[0].selected = 'selected';
}
```

```html
<select id='select-baseline' onchange="saveSelection(value)">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Baseline</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onClick="clearSelection()">Reset menu</button>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `saveSelection` function?

Answer (score 1):

Put all this code inside the `form` tag. This will allow you to apply the clear functionality to the `select` tag and change your `button` type to `reset`

```
<form>
    <select>
        ...
    </select>
    <button type="reset">Reset Menu</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: What, no javascript? Heaven forbid… ;-) This also has the advantage that the *defaultSelected* option can be any option, it doesn't need to be hard-coded in script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="menu" onchange="saveSelection(value)">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Baseline</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="resetMenu()">Reset menu</button>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
function resetMenu() {
    var element = document.getElementById('menu');
    element.value = '';
 }
```